# How to tell if a Flex Spinner List is still spinning?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm having an issue with the Flex Spinner List where I select an option and click a button. What the button does is based on what option is selected in the Spinner List. The problem is that sometimes what is shown on my screen as the index is **not** the **actual** current index of the Spinner List.

I'm assuming this is because the Spinner List hasn't come to a *complete* stop once I've clicked the button (although to me, as a user - it doesn't appear to be moving any longer).

Anyone had any issues with this? Anyone have any idea how to tell if a Spinner List has stopped spinning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research it seems there is no *elegant* solution to my problem, so I wrote the following workaround (for mobile applications):

```
import mx.events.TouchInteractionEvent; 
protected var isScrolling:Boolean=false; //variable to keep up with touch interaction
```

Then in the creationCompleteHandler() I add the following event handlers:

```
myList.scroller.addEventListener(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_START, myListTouchStart);
myList.scroller.addEventListener(TouchInteractionEvent.TOUCH_INTERACTION_END, myListTouchEnd);
```

Then I keep up with whether or not it is scrolling manually in those new event handlers with my variable:

```
protected function myListTouchStart(e:TouchInteractionEvent):void {
            isScrolling=true;
        }

protected function myListTouchEnd(e:TouchInteractionEvent):void {
            isScrolling=false;
        }
```

It isn't the prettiest workaround, but it gets the job done every time with no errors. Hope it helps someone with a similar issue.